# Force complete Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running Jenkins pipeline script.

From this pipeline script we are running one script which keeps on producing output,so this process does not end.

So because of this my Jenkins job is not getting completed but as all the steps completed here i somehow want to mark this job complete after say 10 mins.

Is there any way to complete jenkins job from pipeline scipt after say 10 mins.

Below is my pipeline script and runspbt.sh is that never ending script.

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'Executionmachine3089'}
stages {
   stage('Run Script') {
      steps {  
       bat "ssh rxx11pp@G0XXXX209 /home/rxx11pp/runspbt.sh"
    }
 }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wait and check for some success output (or maybe a marker file in the workspace) .

```
steps{
  sh "sleep 600s"
  script{
         if(testSuccessMethod){
            currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
            return
         }else{currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
            return
   }
}
```

Comment: @lftimie Where i have to add above script ? Just above the never ending script ?

Comment: best would be if you can edit your post and put your whole pipeline changing all the sensitive information. This way others can help you fix your issue and advise on improvements

Comment: @lftimie I have added my pipeline script.

Comment: just to be sure: is Executionmachine3089 an agent running on a windows host ?

Comment: @lftimie Yes  Executionmachine3089 is windows jenkins slave node.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use linux's `timeout` command:

```
pipeline {
 agent { label 'Executionmachine3089' }
 stages {
   stage('Run Script') {
    steps {  
       bat "ssh rxx11pp@G0XXXX209 timeout 90 /home/rxx11pp/runspbt.sh"
    }
   }
 }
}
```

This will start the script and signal it to exit after 90 seconds.

Note this is not related to Jenkins.

Comment: Will this timeout parameter kill the process that are being run by script? I dont want to kill the process it should keep on running.

Comment: You may use `nohup` for that.

Comment: You mean to use nohup and timeout both?